# Observable - don't return results until successful completion

Tags: system.reactive

I have an `IObservable<T>` that comes from parsing a CSV, spitting out a parsed result for each row.

There's an issue right now with corruption in the source data that I cannot detect until I've already reached the end of the file: with the current Reactive setup, that means I've already emitted bad results.

Until the source data issue is resolved, is there a way I can "buffer" (hold back) an entire `IObservable` result stream such that no results are emitted until it has completed successfully?  No method signatures should change (the source should still return `IObservable<T>`).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm sure there's a nicer way, but this should work:

```
// csvObservable is your existing observable
var waitTillEndObservable = csvObservable.ToList().Wait().ToObservable();
```

This converts to a list, waits until it's done, and then converts back to an observable so that it can be used interchangeably with your existing csvObservable.

Comment: No need for the `.Wait().ToObservable()`. The `.ToList()` alone is sufficient. The `.Wait()` blocks the observable.

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much gets the job done, but as you say it is ungainly.  But it is the least disruptive so far.

Comment: @Enigmativity `.ToList` alone is not sufficient because it changes the return type from `IObservable<T> to IObservable<IList<T>>`

Comment: @MarkSowul - But the above code is equivalent, except it is a blocking call. You really don't want a blocking call. If you want to turn the `IObservable<T[]>` back in to a `IObservable<T>`, but avoid blocking then you would do `source.ToArray().SelectMany(t => t)` (or `source.ToList().SelectMany(t => t)`). You really want to avoid `.Wait()`.

Comment: Echoing what @Enigmativity said: This may work for the original questioner, but using `.Wait()` is generally bad advice.

Comment: @Enigmativity I suggest turning your comment into an answer

Comment: @MarkSowul - Done.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy, just do this:

```
var query = source.ToArray();

IDisposable subscription =
    source.Subscribe(allRows =>
    {
        /* do something with `allRows` */
    });
```

The `.ToArray()` operator turns an `IObservable<T>` that returns zero or more values into an `IObservable<T[]>` that returns one array of `T` that contains zero or more elements.

You must make sure that your source observable ends with an `OnCompleted` for the array to be produced.

You can also use `.ToList()` which returns an `IList<T>` rather than an `T[]`.

---

If you want to return a `IObservable<T>` rather than a `IObservable<T[]>` simply put a `.SelectMany(t => t)` after the `.ToArray()`. Keep in mind that this means that all the values will come at once as soon as the source observable completes.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it wasn't clear that things still need to remain as `IObservable` -- there could be multiple places in code that "subscribe" to the `IObservable` so the observable needs to handle this rather than changing all the consumers

Comment: @MarkSowul - Can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: The source needs to change, not the subscriber (the method still needs to return `IObservable<T>`)